# Change the whole content of site depending on monitor resolution

Tags: php, javascript, web, resolution

In my site I am applying a stylesheet depending upon the resolution of the viewer's monitor. By using `screen.width` in javascript i do this. But now I have a doubt that can I use the same technique to change the whole content of the site depending upon the resolution, i.e, for higher resolutions more contents and for lesser, fewer. Or you please suggest me some other technique to do this.

Comment: no i am planning to have only one page, i must change the contents dynamically on load it self

Comment: do you mean window width? It can make a big difference.

Comment: @David: true, but if the user has a small window on a large screen and see scrollbars, they will likely resize/maximise the window. IMO that's a better option that showing a "cut down" design just because their window isn't maximised.

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat: sorry, I should have specified why I asked the question. The OP doesn't want to use javascript...So, my idea is to use CSS float:left and overflow:hidden in combination to only display the content that fits in the window. I imagine it can be done with CSS 2.1; though its would be very limited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could detect the resolution and use this to apply a class to the body of your page and use this to tell CSS to show/hide certain columns. I can provide sample code if you let me know which framework / no framework you're working with.

Here is reallly basic example in plain javascript:

```
window.onload = function(){
 var resolution = 'res'+screen.width;
 document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].className= resolution;
}
```

This also has the advantage that a page will always display regardless of whether JavaScript is enabled or not. If JavaScript is enabled you can tailor the page to the resolution, if not the user will still see your content.

Comment: i am using php and following MVC architecture and implementing my own framework. i like to try your idea.

Comment: haha! yep, i agree. just an example like i said but odds are he will be using a framework with a better dom ready style implementation

Comment: +1.  Also, take a look at SmugMug as they have this whole page scaling thing figured out... http://philipjoep.smugmug.com/Other/Colorado/

Answer (score 0):

Have your initial page load return an empty container and execute an ajax call that will populate it with the content.  The ajax call can pass the resolution as a parameter so you can return the appropriate content accordingly.

Comment: This would work but it makes the whole process rely on JavaScript being enabled. No JavaScript = No Content

Comment: Duh!, obviously you would have a no script version!

Comment: The questions mentions screen.width -- obviously javascript is already being used here.

Answer (score 0):

As you're already serving alternate stylesheets based on the screen width, you can just set the content that you don't want for that given stylesheet to `display:none`.